# two threads call DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net

When I use webclient.downloadfileAsync and have a web exception, I found there is an empty file written. when I use webclient.downloadfile, there is no such empty file.

How can I make the downloadfileAsync behave the same as downloadfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the empty file in the `catch(WebExcpetion e)`-block?

Comment: Actually don't like this way.

Comment: He doesn't like it.  Format the drive then?